# Git push not showing new branch on remote

Tags: git

I made a new local branch:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

then change some files, and commit:

```
git commit -am "comments"
```

and then pushed to remote:

```
git push origin new_branch
```

It looks like it worked, i see message:

```
* [new branch]   new_branch -> new_branch
```

i then do:

```
git branch -a
```

but i don't see my new branch under remotes/origin but i see it for local.
I try a pull,

```
git pull
```

and git says everything is "Already up-to-date"

I tried

```
git fetch --all
```

same result from

```
git branch -a
```

What am i missing? i don't recall having to do anything different in the past.

I want to be able to do things like:

```
git diff new_branch origin/new_branch
```

but origin/new_branch doesn't show up
All my other branches show up as remotes/origin/branchname

Comment: what does `git remote -v` say?

Comment: `git remote -v`   shows `origin user@myserver:/repopath/gitname.git  (fetch)`   and `origin <same address above>  (push)`

Comment: Well, i was able to see my new branches if i made a new local clone of the remote repo.  so i guess that proves the branches are on the remote, just not from the local repo folder i was using.

Comment: I have seen this (and other strange) behavior before with Git.  It is open source and no law says it will not have any bugs or quirks.  When you did a <code>git pull</code> and everything was already up to date, that basically confirmed that the remote branch existed in the origin.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All suggestions pointed to the remote repo actually having the correct info.  Since a new clone of remote repo worked perfectly and showed previously missing branches, it seems like the behavior is from a some how corrupted local repo.

Thanks for help.

Thanks to:

`I have seen this (and other strange) behavior before with Git. It is open source and no law says it will not have any bugs or quirks. When you did a <code>git pull</code> and everything was already up to date, that basically confirmed that the remote branch existed in the origin. –  Tim Biegeleisen`

Answer (score 2):

The first time you push a branch you should do:

`git push --set-upstream origin branch-name`

You can do it now if you didn't do it the first time.

```
-u, --set-upstream
  For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
  upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) 
  and other commands. For more information, see branch.<name>.merge 
  in git-config(1).
```

Comment: tried this on the existing repo, didn't change behavior. I also made a new branch and pushed using --set-upstream but same issue.  However, on a newly cloned folder from the same remote all worked fine.  I am thinking my local repo must have been corrupted somehow., thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is sometimes happening and unable to find the remote branch. However, if you follow the link by Github in initial push:

```
repository_name/compare/branch_name_you_are_merging_to...name_of_your_remote_branch?quick_pull=1
```

I was able to actually PR it even tho I was not able to see the remote branch I pushed.

E.g.

```
If I trying to push typo_fix branch to next.js's main.

repository_name: https://github.com/vercel/next.js
```

So, `https://github.com/vercel/next.js/compare/main...typo_fix?quick_pull=1`